# What is the influence when updating net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range?

Tags: linux, operating-system

Our existing ip local port range configuration on server is

*net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 32768    61000*

Now, we want to extend that range by updating it to

*net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 10000    61000*

On our server, we have services that are running on ports **20xxx** and those ports are covered by the updated port range.

I know that ip local port range is used for server to dynamically grant to TCP/UDP traffics on the server.

**My question is:**

Is there any influence to our services if my server's local port range is updated to cover their using ports ? For example, there may be a moment of collision/conflict in port usage between the services and traffics on server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid conflicts, there is another option, `ip_local_reserved_ports`. Add your **20xxx** ports to it. [Documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you think that operation system is smart enough to know a certain port was in used already and does not assign that port to new connections ?

Comment: @ChiếnNghê, OS is free to choose any port for outgoing connection which satisfies **all** of the following: 1) it falls into `ip_local_port_range`; 2) it does not fall into `ip_local_reserved_ports`; 3) it is not _currently_ in use.

Comment: That is great information for me! Just a confirmation about answer for my questions, so, there will not be any influence on my running services regarding port conflict even if their ports are not in ip_local_reserved_ports because those ports are currently in use right ?

Comment: That's correct. (But if your service which listens on **20xxx** becomes shut down, then OS may decide to use its port for outgoing connections.)